# Accessing an arraylist of string type of an activity from another fragment in android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, arraylist

I have an arraylist of string type in one activity. I need this arraylist to be accessed from another fragment in my application. What should I do to access this arraylist from any fragment. Please suggest me a solution. I don't know the procedure to do it. Can someone please help me out..

Comment: save it in sahred pref

Comment: You can pass data between activity using putExtra method [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra) . This requires that the class that represents the object of the array must implements the Parcelable interface.

Comment: As others are suggesting you should store your data to db or shared preferences. If you are doing it correct, you can use this code on fragment --> ((ActivityClassName) getActivity()).variableName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your ArrayList is static, you can pass it as an argument to your Fragment instantiation.

In your Activity:

```
Bundle b=new Bundle();
b.putStringArrayList('myarraylist',myarraylist)
MyFragment f=MyFragment.newInstance(b);
```

In your MyFragment class:

```
public MyFragment newInstance(b){
    MyFragment myfragment=new MyFragment();
    myFramgent.setArguments(b);
    return myFragment;
}
```

In case it is a dynamic ArrayList, an option would be to get a reference to your fragments in your Activity and call a set method (you had defined in your fragments or a common interface) on each change to pass in your data.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad idea to store your data in an Activity in Android. Activities might get destroyed and your local data like ArrayLists could become unaccessable. This is why you need to store your info somewhere else. Most common places are a database or preferences.

Have a look at this page where they recommend data storage options:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to store ur arraylist :

```
 public static boolean saveArray() {  
         SharedPrefernces sp=SharedPrefernces.getDefaultSharedPrefernces(this);  
         SharedPrefernces.Editor mEdit1= sp.edit();  
         mEdit1.putInt("Status_size",sKey.size()); /*sKey is an array*/   

        for(int i=0;i<sKey.size();i++) {  
            mEdit1.remove("Status_" + i);  
            mEdit1.putString("Status_" + i, sKey.get(i));    
        }  

        return mEdit1.commit();       
    }
```

Use this method to retrieve

```
public static void loadArray(Context mContext) {    
    Shared Preferences mSharedPreference1=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);  
    sKey.clear();  
    int size = mSharedPreference1.getInt("Status_size", 0);    

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {  
        sKey.add(mSharedPreference1.getString("Status_" + i, null));    

    }  
}
```